# Use loop for plotting, but plot only particular images from the plot

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, plot, healpy

I have to use different csv files to create plots out of them in the same figure. My coding environment is google colab (it's like Jupyter notebook in google's cloud). So I decided to create a figure and then loop through the files and do the plots. It looks something like this:

```
import healpy as hp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for void_file in ['./filepath1.csv','./filepath2.csv','./filepath3.csv', ...]:
   helper_image = hp.gnomview(void_file, .....)
   data = func1(helper_image, .....)
   plt.plot(len(data), data, ......)
```

What I want is to only add into the figure the plots created with the line `plt.plot(len(data), data, ......)`, but what happens is that also the helper images from the line `helper_image = hp.gnomview(....)` sneak into the image and spoil it (`healpy` is a package for spherical data). The line `helper_image = ....` is only there to make some necessary calculations, but unfortunately they come along with plots.

How can I suppress the creation of the plots by `helper_image = hp.gnomview(....)`? Or can I somehow tell the figure or `ax` to include only plots that I specify? Or are there any easy alternatives that don't require a loop for plotting? Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `return_projected_image=True` and `no_plot=True` keyword arguments, see https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/healpy.visufunc.gnomview.html

Comment: Thanks, `no_plot=True` solved my problem! I didn't know such an option exist

Comment: good, unfortunately the function accepts a looot of parameters